# Linear Hamiltonian System

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Suppose the linear system: $\dot{z} = J \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{z}} = J S(t) z = A(t) z$, with Hamiltonian $H=H(t,z)=\frac{1}{2} z^T S(t)z$.

How can I prove that:

$$\frac{d}{dt}H(t,\xi(t)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}H(t, \xi(t))$$

being $\xi(t)$ a solution of the linear system?

Notes:
\begin{equation*}
J=\left[
\begin{matrix} 
0  \ I \\ 
-I  \ 0 
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{equation*}
$A(t) = JS(t)$ are matrices.

Thank you

Comment: $J$ is missing a minus sign? Have you tried writing $\frac{d H}{d t}$ explicitly? Try to do that and then use the equations of motion. :)

Comment: Yes you're right! There's a missing minus in J, I edit it. Thanks

Comment: Anyway I don't know how to start... I mean, how do I find dH/dt?

Comment: I think you need to additionally assume matrix $S(t)$ is a symmetric matrix with dimension $2k \times 2k$ (even dimensional).

Comment: By the chain rule we know that for any function $G(u,z)$ and any functions $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ we have $\frac{d}{dt} \left[G(r(t), s(t))\right] = r'(t)^T\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(r(t),s(t))\right] + s'(t)^T\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} G(r(t),s(t)) \right]$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to additionally assume that $S(t)$ is a symmetric matrix for all $t$, and that it has even dimension $2k \times 2k$.  Here are some hints (without giving away the whole solution). Let’s first simplify notation (to avoid using the $t$ variable in two different ways, which is confusing to me).

Define:

$$H(u, z)  = (1/2)z^T S(u) z$$

Thus: 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} H(u,z) &= (1/2)z^TS’(u)z \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} H(u,z) &= (1/2)(S(u) + S(u)^T)z = S(u)z 
\end{align}
where the last equality holds by the symmetry assumption $S(u)=S(u)^T$.

You are asked to show that for any solution $\xi(t)$ to your differential equation, we have: 
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left[H(t, \xi(t))\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} H(t, \xi(t)) $$
Since we already know $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} H(u,z)$, proving the above equation is equivalent to proving that: 
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left[H(t, \xi(t))\right] = (1/2)\xi(t)^TS’(t)\xi(t) $$

To do this, you will need to use the chain rule, and then eventually use properties of the $J$ matrix.

---

Recall: The chain rule is as follows:  Let $G(u,z)$ be a real-valued function of vectors $u$ and $z$, and let $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ be vector-valued functions of time variable $t$.  Then by the chain rule: 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left[G(r(t),s(t))\right] = r’(t)^T\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(r(t),s(t))\right] + s’(t)^T \left[  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} G(r(t),s(t))\right] $$

Comment: The assumptions you do are all correct. S(t) is symmetric, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}H(u,z)=S(u)z$.

If I understood it right, I must prove:
$$\frac{d}{dt}[H(t,\xi(t))]= \frac{1}{2}\xi(t)^T S'(t) \xi(t)$$
I obtain:

$$\frac{d}{dt}[H(t,\xi(t))]=t'^T [\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}H(t,\xi(t))] + \xi'(t)^T [\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}H(t,\xi(t))] = \frac{1}{2}\xi(t)^T S'(t) \xi(t) + \xi'(t)^T S(t) \xi(t)$$

But this will be equal to 
$$\frac{1}{2}\xi(t)^T S'(t) \xi(t)$$

just if the second part is equal to zero... Am I right or I'm completely lost?

Thank you!!

Comment: @Cherax ,  Your work is correct.  Now you need to use properties of the $J$ matrix to prove the second term is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found a property that I think solves the problem without having to use chain rule and is easier:

$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \{f, H\}$

where $\{, \}$ is the Poisson Bracket.

$\{f,H\} = \nabla f^T J \nabla H$

As property, $\{F, H\}  = 0 $ if and only if F is an integral of $\dot{z}=J\nabla H(t,z)$, and we know that H is an integral of this equation.

This way we have: $\{H,H\} = 0$

$\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial t} + \{H, H\} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$